# How to check the angle of a swipe in corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want a certain function to take place when a person swipes right or left, but I do not want the function to execute if a person slides its finger diagonally. Is there a simple way to do this? Currently I am working with this code:

```
display.setDefault("background", 0.2, 0.2, 0.4 )

local function startDrag(event)
    local swipeLength = math.abs(event.x - event.xStart) 
    print(event.phase, swipeLength)
    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase
    if "began" == phase then
        return true
    elseif "moved" == phase then
    elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
        if event.xStart > event.x and swipeLength > 50 then 
            display.setDefault("background", 0/255,3/255, 0/255 )
        elseif event.xStart < event.x and swipeLength > 50 then 
            display.setDefault("background", 0, 0, 1 )
        end 
    end
end

local rectangle= display.newRect(100,200,1000,1000)
rectangle:setFillColor(1,1,1,0.1)
rectangle:addEventListener("touch",startDrag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When event phase is "ended" I would also check for y positions. For example,

```
if (event.y - 5 <= event.yStart and event.y + 5 >= event.yStart) then

   -- almost perfect line, 
   -- if someone draws a line from bottom-left to top-right, it won't work
end
```

You can test and change 5 or -5 to something that works good for you.